Android : drawing on canvas from another canvas, bad performance
I have a custom view where in onDraw(Canvas canvas), I need to draw on offscreen canvas, then draw the bitmap of offscreen canvas on view's canvas.
Here the code in the view class :
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas offscreenCanvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
  //Draw stuff in offscreen canvas :
  offscreenCanvas.drawRect(..);

  //Draw offscreen canvas bitmap to view canvas :
  canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, ...);
}

In ActivityMain.java, I call invalidate() every 16ms to update view canvas.
The problem is that application slowdown because new Canvas(bitmap) is not hardware accelerated.
So is there a workaround ?

AFAIK you can't create a hardware accelerated canvas backed by a bitmap.
This is probably due to the fact that a canvas requires a mutable bitmap, but hardware bitmaps are always immutable.
Some options:

Draw the geometry directly to the view's canvas. This is supposed to be hardware accelerated.
And if you are concerned with the overhead of drawing multiple shapes, then consider using a Picture for drawing in batches.

Do the offscreen rendering using OpenGL ES.
And make sure to do it on a background thread.



Thank you very much, I will try the first option, because openGL ES is too complex for me.

I try the first option, so picture is faster than using new Canvas(bitmap). Now, I would like to draw a "part" of picture (not the whole picture) on the canvas, like canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, srcRect, dstRect, paint) method with srcRect and dstRect parameters. So I convert picture to bitmap with Bitmap.createBitmap(picture, width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888), but it slowdown, so is there a way to draw a part of picture to canvas without slowdown ?

I'm not sure about partial pictures.
